# The browse button is not showing in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

The code is basically gives a browse button to browse pc files:

```py
def _upload():

    _upload_widget = fileupload.FileUploadWidget()

    def _cb(change):
        global file_contents
        decoded = io.StringIO(change['owner'].data.decode('utf-8'))
        filename = change['owner'].filename
        print('Uploaded `{}` ({:.2f} kB)'.format(
            filename, len(decoded.read()) / 2 **10))
        file_contents = decoded.getvalue()

    _upload_widget.observe(_cb, names='data')
    display(_upload_widget)

_upload()
```

But the output is:

```
FileUploadWidget(label='Browse', _dom_classes=('widget_item', 'btn-group'))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you had a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495994/uploading-files-using-browse-button-in-jupyter-and-using-saving-them here?

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading files using Browse Button in Jupyter and Using/Saving them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495994/uploading-files-using-browse-button-in-jupyter-and-using-saving-them)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that after running the code, this button shows "Trusted" as in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV4Ve.png)
, else click on it and confirm that it is trusted.

Your "Browse" button should show after this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).